# Blazor wasm save html to byte[]

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm application in which i am generating a razor component as report. I want to save this razor page as pdf in the database. How can i convert the blazor razor page to pdf byte[] on the client side and send to API?